# Kubernetes: storage shared between different deployments

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

I have a system consist of 2 applications: `Application 1` and `Application 2`. Fundamentally, those applications are perfectly sync in term of reading\writing from storage.

### System arch:

[image]

### How it working today?

`Application 1` is downloading a file from the internet and store it on Google Cloud Storage. Than, the URI passed to the shared queue. Once `Application 2` is ready, it pull the queue message and downloading the URI to the memory and continue the processing.

### What change I want to make?

I want to replace the Google Cloud Storage with another internal storage system that built-in in Kubernetes. Since my application are perfectly synced, its guaranteed that `Application 2` will read from the storage only when `Application 1` already finished the writing.

What kind of Kubernetes storage you recommend to adapt? How to implement it?

Comment: What are max/average file size? With few large file (limited to 5 MiB for pubsub) or many small files, storage may be omitted. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Filestore service offered witihin GCP as a storage solution for Kubernetes app that you will be creating.

The Filestore supports "`ReadWriteMany`" access for your apps to use. You can see official documentation and implementation via this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/filestore-for-gke). For additional info about Kubernetes `volumeMount` and `volumeClaims` you check this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/#mounting-the-same-persistentvolume-in-two-places).

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes only includes a couple of built-in storage types and these can't generally be accessed from multiple nodes at the same time.

If you look at the list of [volume types](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#volume-types) they generally use cloud disk-type storage (`gcePersistentDisk` but not GCS; formerly `awsElasticBlockStore` but not S3), Kubernetes objects directly (`configMap`, `secret`, `downwardAPI`), or a couple of very local storage options (`emptyDir`, `local`).  There are a couple of multi-node-accessible options like `nfs`, but they require an external server.

It's also worth noting that traditional filesystems and cloud object-storage systems have different guarantees.  You describe a read-after-write constraint, for example, and you'd have to implement this yourself using filesystem primitives (and hope they work consistently in a distributed environment).

I might stay with what you have, maybe substituting an object-storage server that could run in the cluster if you don't want to have a public-cloud dependency.  I don't think anything built into Kubernetes can satisfy the need you describe.